# Need help pulling in object value as jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm pretty new to OOP concepts in general, and I'm trying to build this mini-application for a client. The idea is that it's supposed to have configurable options based on the Module number, etc. I've cut out some code to keep relevant stuff. I'm trying to make this as customizable as possible, in particular--allowing the coder to support multiple Lightbox-style popups by adding them to the options array below.

Everything has worked great until this--my issue is that I'm trying to bind each object in the `options.popups` array with jQuery, by feeding `selector` as a string in through the config, directly into a `$()` selector.

This works fine for binding `click()` to the opener, but the `selector` property just won't bind. Every time, I get this error: `TypeError: self.options.popups[i] is undefined.` If I directly insert the selector, e.g. `$(".helpPopup").show();`, it works fine. If I define it in a variable within the `click()` function directly above it, it works. e.g. `var s = ".helpPopup";`

Is there some obvious thing that I'm missing here? This is driving me nuts. Also, my code's design pattern is directly based off of this: https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-plugin-patterns/prototypal-inheritance.html

Thanks!

```
var MODULE = {
    init: function(options, elem) {
        // Stuff here

        this.bindPopups();
    },

    options: {
        title: "Module title",
        pages: 1,
        currentPage: 1,
        windowOpener: ".popupVar",
        popups: [
            { 
                name: "help", 
                selector: ".helpPopup", 
                opener: ".button.open", 
                closer: ".button.close",
                type: 3
            }
        ]
    },

    bindPopups: function() {
        var self = this;

        for(i = 0; i < this.options.popups.length; i++) {
            // Open the popup
            $(self.options.popups[i].opener).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(self.options.popups[i].selector).show();
            });

            // Close the popup
            $(self.options.popups[i].closer).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(self.options.popups[i].selector).hide();
            });
        }
    }
};

// If browser doesn't support Object.create
if(typeof Object.create !== "function") {
    Object.create = function(o) {
        function F() {
            F.prototype = o;
            return new F();
        }
    };
}

// Create plugin
$.plugin = function(name, object) {
    $.fn[name] = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if(!$.data(this, name)) {
                $.data(this, name, Object.create(object).init(options, this));
            }
        });
    };
};

$.plugin("module", MODULE);



/* PAGE CODE */
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("body").module({
            title: "Module 1",
            pages: 12,
            popups: [
                { 
                    name: "help", 
                    selector: ".helpPopup", 
                    opener: ".button.open", 
                    closer: ".button.close",
                    type: 3
                },
                {
                    name: "info",
                    selector: ".infoPopup",
                    opener: ".button.info",
                    closer: ".button.close",
                    type: 1
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, your `i` is incrementing inside your click function. To verify, put one `console.log(i);` right before the click event functions, and one inside the open click function.

<s>I don't know why it's doing this (I don't see any obvious bugs), but one quick hack would be to put `var j = i;` right after you open the `for` loop, and use `j` as your index selector.</s>

EDIT: the hack above only works for one iteration. The `i` "appears" to be incrementing here because it is not evaluated until after the `for` loop is closed, at which point `i` has incremented (for the click event). You can verify this for example by logging `i` inside a `setTimeout` function.

To get the appropriate value of `i`, you have to wrap the click event function in an anonymous function like this:

```
$(self.options.popups[i].opener).click(
    (function (i) { 
        return function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(self.options.popups[i].selector).show();
        }
    })(i)
);
```

For more information

Comment: Thanks kardeiz--this worked. I'm not exactly sure why this is even happening--it could be some flaw in some other aspect of my code..but this fix will be fine for now.

Comment: Hi Andrew--sorry, the hack I suggested previously doesn't really work. I've updated my answer with a real solution.